# Trying to mount shared Windows 10 folder on virtual machine vmware Linux Centos and it gives me: mount error(13): Permision denied

Tags: linux, centos, windows, vmware

I am trying to mount a shared folder from windows 10 to a vmware virtual machine linux centos with this command :

```
mount -t cifs //ip/folder /mnt/win -o username=xxx,password=xxx,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,uid=root
```

and it give me

```
mount error(13): Permision denied
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Do you run it as root?

If not:

```
sudo mount -t cifs //ip/folder /mnt/win -o username=xxx,password=xxx,file_mode=0644,dir_mode=0755,uid=root
```